# List folders that don't contain a specific file

Tags: windows, batch-file

In Windows 10 Batch file, How do I save in a text file all the folders (full path) that don't contain a file named "test" in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
IF "%~1"=="" (%0 .) ELSE (FOR /d /r "%~1" %%e IN (*) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%e\test" ECHO %%e)>reportfilename
```

Where you execute *thisbatchname* "?:\directory\name\to start\from"

If you don't provide an argument, the `if` re-executes the routine passing and argument of `.` which lists from the current directory.

The argument must be quoted as shown if it contains non-alphameric data like <kbd>Space</kbd> or some other symbols.